# Screen resolution is not saved after reboot

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution, xorg.conf

I'm using Xubuntu 15.10 on my [GA-C847N](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4419) motherboard.

I can set appropriate resolution using the following command:

`sudo xrandr -s 1440x900`

However, each time after machine is rebooted I'm getting some weird distorted resolution and I need to change it manually again. During this time I can't open the Display Settings dialogue, the window of this dialogue is black and it crashes.

I'm experiencing this problem after switching to the old monitor `Acer AL1916W` connected via `VGA` interface.

Before that I was using a newer monitor via `HDMI` and it worked flawlessly.

What could be the reason for this? How do I preserve the resolution. Maybe I need to pre-generate the `xorg.conf` file? How do I do that for my configuration?

I used to have NVIDIA descrete graphic adapters and I'm not familiar with embedded ones.

Comment: At the expense of sounding unhelpful .... just dont use the VGA monitor. Your system works connected via HDMI.  I try hard not to give answers like this usually but wonder if you need to bother with this. That said,  boot into  a live 14.04 environment and see if that works for starters. I stopped using non LTS releases a while a go as I always seemed to hit issues just like this one.

Comment: Sadly, this monitor only has one VGA input port. No way to use HDMI with it. And thanks for the LTS hint, I will consider it. However, I will prefer to solve this problem nevertheless. In the end current workaround is a better option than reinstalling the whole system again = )

Comment: You lose nothing by booting into a live 14.04LTS disc, dont install it just run it. It will not touch your installed system. If the VGA works properly it might be food for thought.

Comment: Yeah I know. I just can't see how it will help me to solve the issue with my current system though = )

Comment: Because you will then know it is a 15.10 issue (or not), and can then decide whether all you can do is use a workaround. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If local screen settings are not "surviving" a reboot or re- log in, your issue is almost certainly the result of a bug. For that reason, it is very hard, if possible at all, to solve without a workaround, since the issue occurs *locally*, and possible global settings are simply overruled with incorrect local settings.

To solve (workaround) the issue, we need to (re-) confirm our own settings on log in, by adding a command to Startup Applications.

#### What to do

*If* your screen is set correctly when using the command

```
xrandr -s 1440x900
```

(no need for `sudo`), just add the following to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && xrandr -s 1440x900"
```

It is a workaround, but it works. The sleep 10 is needed to make sure the screen setting will not be overruled by local procedures on log in. ten seconds after log in, your screen will be set correctly automatically.

Possibly you need to play a bit with the 10 seconds.

#### To make it work for all users

1. Create a .desktop file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=set_screen
   Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && xrandr -s 1440x900"
   Type=Application
   ```

   save it as `set_screen.desktop`
2. Copy the file into `/etc/xdg/autostart`

Now the command will run for *all users* during log in.

Comment: That's a clever automation, I was going to use something like this until I will manage to fix the problem. Thanks! But is there a way to run this code for all users of the OS? )

Comment: @SlavaFominII Absolutely, will edit in a minute.

Comment: Also, I think there should be a way to pre-generate the `xorg.conf` file and put this configuration option into it. However, I wasn't being able to find the way to do it. Do you have experience with it? )

Comment: @SlavaFominII the problem is that it is a bug, (locally) overruling the screen setting on log in. Very hard to find out, if possible at all. See my latest edit.

Comment: This is a pretty good workaround, I think I can live with it for now. Thanks, for helping me out ; )

Comment: @SlavaFominII *if* the answer solved your problem, as you indicated, would you consider to accept the answer?

Comment: I think I'm going to give it some more time, maybe this problem will attract some more attention from someone who would be able to help me to find the roots of this issue. If not, I will gladly accept it, as it's a suitable solution ))

Comment: @SlavaFominII The root of the problem is that your system and the screen do not understand each other on log in, and the system jumps to a generic setting, no matter what you set. re- confirming your own setting *after* login will then restore. Switching driver might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread. Just wanted to update it.
These days the program arandr - a GUI frontend for xrandr is available.

For ubuntu-based distros, use apt to install:

```
    sudo -H apt install arandr
```